# Block alerts, or any custom popups by javascript for chrome browser

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-chrome

I want to block any type of popup or alert that comes over window in chrome browser,as i'm using selenium with java for accessing the document element and taking screenshots while scrolling.
But,
here sometimes a popup comes over the window and hide some element while taking screenshot.
Any idea how to stop this custom popup in generic script,like for most of the websites through javascript?

Comment: you can use css property on popup html like `display:block`.

Comment: @saddam actually im working on like 100s of website, then by that i have to go through each popup element of each website , which will not be generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
    try {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @PankajAnuragi you need to provide more information regarding your custom popup, If its control by browser.

Comment: im trying to implement this for generic cases, like on this website [link](https://curiosity.com/topics/heres-why-the-perseid-meteor-shower-shows-up-once-a-year-curiosity)   ,here the pop-up comes after some time, so in this cases in your code i have add wait , which will increase my execution time , therefore , i'm looking for some javascript  that i can execute through javascriptExecuter in  the beginning to stop or block any type of pop-up to showup that can cover window.